# Is there an alternative to avatars.io?

Tags: service, photo, avatars, avatars.io

As http://avatars.io seems to return 404 instead of already uploaded photos, and does not allow to upload new photos, I found myself in an inconvenient situation, where I have to move to a different service provider or implement my own avatars solution.
The latter (based on my experience from nk.pl) seems to be quite time consuming, and I do not want users of my website to wait for this basic functionality, so I'd really love to hear that there is some drop-in replacement for avatars.io.

I need a service which :

1. allows a user to upload a photo to the cloud (preferably directly from their browser using a js library)
2. stores the photo, resizes it, crops it to a square shape
3. after the upload returns a url which can be stored in the database and subsequently used to retrieve the avatar